# App being selected from recent app list - behavior not consistent

Tags: java, android, restart

I have an app that uses the motion sensor to monitor the user indefinitely.  Sometimes the monitoring will be 5 minutes, sometimes 4 hours.  Regardless, the app will get pushed to the background but needs to stay operational.  When bringing the app to the foreground (by selecting it from the recent app list) 95% of the time it all works as expected.  The other 5% of the time, the app restarts, losing all the recorded data.  I can't figure out (1) what triggers the different behavior or (2) how to keep the app from restarting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app is restarted or not depends if it was terminated by the system in the meantime. This will usually happen if your device needs more memory for other applications but can generally happen at any time so you should not rely on your app continue running in the background. You can easily test this by using a device with little memory or by starting an app which needs a lot of memory, e.g. a game.

**Solution:**
First, you should make sure the collected data is persisted permanently and not only kept in memory as soon as you collect it. For example you can store the data in a local database or the Android shared preferences. By doing so you can retrieve the data later also if the app was terminated. 
If you additionally want to make sure that the device continues the monitoring even if it runs low on memory, you can use a foreground service. (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer.  I will look into all your suggestions and accept the answer in due time.